# Divergence theorem in index notation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation

From Batchelor's book of fluid dynamics:

[image]

I guess that's an easy question for anyone having more familiartiy than me in tensor calculus, anyways.

First integral argument is the i-component of the torque and i can write it up as shown.

Im struggling understanding how the dot product between the $\nabla$ operator and the argument is being applied here.

Where $n_l$ went?
Why exactly the "$l$" index has been chosen?

Assuming ive understood why left side writes like that, Levi-Civita goes out simply because isn't a funcion of spacial coordinates and the leibntz rule gives me the last equation...

...except i miss a $\delta_{jl}$, wich did some trickery with the stress tensor indexing i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps you visualize if we expand things out. Let $A_{il} = \epsilon_{ijk}r_{j}\sigma_{kl}$,  such that the first integral is:

$$\tau_{i} = \displaystyle{\int A_{il}n_{l} dA}$$

Notice that we can write $A_{il}n_{l} = A_{i 1}n_{1} + A_{i 2}n_{2}+ A_{i 3}n_{3}$, from which it is clear that $\nabla \cdot A_{il} = \dfrac{\partial A_{il}}{\partial r_{l}}$. As for the Kronecker delta, it simply comes from

$$\dfrac{\partial r_{j}}{\partial r_{i}} = \delta_{ij}$$

Comment: I can see where the delta comes from but i cannot see why it disappears

Comment: Oh, it got contracted: $\sigma_{kl} \delta_{lj} = \sigma_{kj}$

Comment: And where $n_l$ went?

Comment: Check the precise mathematical statement of the divergence theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: So im just considering $n_l$ as the second vector in the dot product with my vector field $"F"$ being $F=\epsilon_{ijk} r_j \sigma_{kl}$? But if that's' the case isn't $F=F_{il}$ so not a vector field but a order two tensor?

Comment: It is indeed a rank two tensor because the result of the integral is not a scalar, but a component of a vector. That does not affect the divergence theorem, though. Formally, you can apply the divergence theorem to the integral of tensors of any rank, provided you act with the divergence on the index that is contracted into the normal vector $n$. If you want to learn more about this, take a look at external derivatives and the differential geometry behind Stokes' theorem.